# Nvidia driver on Windows 7 causing black screen

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, black-screen-of-death

I have just installed Windows 7 on a desktop machine and for the first time ever have had a really tough time doing so, its normally a nice smooth install. This time I found that the monitor would simply go black after completing the installation.

I tried reinstalling about 3 times and this did not help.

After much searching I discovered that it was the nvidia drivers that were playing up with win 7, so i booted into safe mode, disabled the device, then rebooted to complete the installation.

Windows 7 now works fine as long as the nvidia 9600 gt video card is disabled. The moment I enable it, the system requires a reboot and the screen will go black before even getting to the log in screen.

I have tried downloading the latest driver and installing it manually, I have also tried uninstalling the device and allowing windows 7 to install it itself. Nothing seems to work.

any clues?

Comment: Are there any bios settings you can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted into low resolution mode then set the resolution to the screens optimum mode. I don't know why this worked, but i assume that it allowed some sort of configuration on nvidia's part so that the driver worked properly.

Answer (score -1):

Nvidia 8xxx and 9xxx GPU have problems. I've faced it too, it worked only in non-driver mode. Last time I used a heat gun to fry it, it works. If you don't have a heat gun, you can use your oven.

Comment: "Oh problem with graphics card? Just fry it!" Best advice I've seen all day...